# How to set an option true/false with mat-select (multiselect) Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, multi-select

I used a multiple selection from Angular Material .

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to put some options on true or false as I want and I don't know how.

**before** 
[image]
**after**
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking about how to set some options as true by default?

Comment: yes, I want to set some options on true because I recived from API data selected and unselected depending  onSelectionChange event

Comment: @Madalina, remember that a mat-multiselect expect an array, in this case an array of strings, e.g. ['Onion','Sausage']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the response would be coming from an API, you would receive the response asynchronously.

In that case, you can call the `setValue` method on your `FormControl` instance or `FormGroup` instance in order to set the values by default.

Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppingList: string[] = [
    'Extra cheese',
    'Mushroom',
    'Onion',
    'Pepperoni',
    'Sausage',
    'Tomato'
  ];
  selectedByDefault;
  toppings: FormControl;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toppings = new FormControl(this.selectedByDefault);
    this.dataService.selectedValues$
      .subscribe(values => this.toppings.setValue(values));
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-multi-select-by-default-eg?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple matter of defaulting your form values. When initializing your FormGroup, just pass in which values you'd like to show as "checked", making sure to match the values exactly.

Working stackblitz --> https://angular-r2y6gk.stackblitz.io